any ideas for reducing the size of the linked PDF's PPI while working?
I need to reduce the size of the linked PDF's PPI while working.
It's hard to work because progress keeps getting interrupted by too many PDFs in the file.
I need to reduce PPI while just working, not for artwork result.
Hope to there are some preference setting or something..
any hint for me please?

Hide what you aren't editing. Object > Hide
Or put them on layers and set the players to Outline Mode (Command/ctrl-click the layer eyeball in the panel.)
It's not possible tt "reduce the PPI" of placed/embedded images or PDFs.

Well obviously you can re rasterize them with  the rasterize effect to lower pixel count. dont know if it does anything for performance though. Atleast memory consumption goes up if you do this. But possibly you could then export them as lower res and re link them? But then memory and disk is cheap compared to a human.

I was assuming the PDFs were more than simple raster images.. rasterizing native vector content would actually decrease redraw performance in my experience.

yeah but just rasterize images again, or rasterizing the group of vectors.
